# Как отсортировать и удалить лишние неймспейсы во всех файлах в VisualStudio 2022?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Как отсортировать и удалить лишние неймспейсы во всех файлах в VisualStudio 2022, чтобы не заходить в каждый из них и не вызывать эту команду, а стразу выполнить для всех?

Comment: Пока вы ждете здесь ответа, уже бы сделали всё вручную, ведь нужно примерно 10 секунд, чтобы обработать один файл.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12075920/12888024

Comment: `Ctrl + K`, `Ctrl + E`, надо нажать последовательно, тогда студия сама почистит файл и лишних пробелов, табуляции, юзинги и прочее